# Eclipse RCP: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException a runtime

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

One of my plugins uses a library (jar file).

1. I created a folder called lib in my plugin and placed the jar file into it.
2. I configured the build path by adding the jar file with "Add JARS..".
3. I use the classes of the jar file in the plugin and it compiles fine.
4. I start the RCP and get a ClassNotFoundException about the classes in the jar file.

What am I missing?

Comment: Does the JAR contain src files or compiled .class files?

Comment: It contains a package with .class files and a META-INF folder for the manifest file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of OSGi! :D

***You have two options:***

## Repack the JAR as an OSGi bundle

You can go the OSGi way and repack your JAR in an OSGi bundle. This is clean and recommended in the sense of OSGi, since all code should be packaged in OSGi bundles (which in you case are called *Eclipse plugins*). However, this means additional work and I personally do not like it.

## Use the bundle class path

Put the JAR file to the root (or a folder called `lib`) of your bundle and add a `Bundle-ClassPath` entry to your manifest:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: .,lib/library.jar
```